# Why does Si donate its own electron to Al in a p-type semi conductor losing its own stability?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

**Things I have known or been taught before asking this question:**

1. Every electron does not absorb same amount of energy from the environment. So there are some electrons in a semiconductor which can absorb enough energy to leave their orbital and roam freely. They shift from valence band to conduction band.
2. Free electrons usually do not fill up the holes of a p-type semiconductor
3. Few bonding electrons of Si-Si leave their bonding electron to fill the holes generated due to doping. And this results in movement of holes throughout the material. It is comparable to resonance in a cation having $\sigma$-$\pi$-$(+)$ successive arrangement.

I have asked the following question based on these ideas which are perhaps wrong

Let's say we are talking about silicon semiconductor doped with aluminium or boron. All these are p-block elements and as far as I know they have been observed to be stable when their octets are filled. When Al or B is doped we all know that they will form covalent bonds (3 covalent bonds) with Si. As far as I know due to polarization Al forms covalent bond.

Now, since their octets aren't filled, they will tend to find a electron to form another covalent bond with Si. But why would adjacent Si donate one of its electron to Al? I mean aren't those Si's losing their stability too? Why would one atom lose its own stability to provide another atom stability? Is it the thermal energy gained from the surroundings which lets electrons to leave its location and move to another location (orbital), just as we see during the formation of atomic spectra?

I know all these things don't work that way as I have mentioned, there are a bunch of extremely sophisticated phenomena taking place during those moments. I don't want to dig that far (at least for now), but the least thing I can do is avoid wrong ideas, which is basically why I am asking this question.

Comment: I personally think there are too many questions in your question, with some confusions. I would be willing to answer them if they were posted separately, but asked like that, the question is too "messy". I think it needs to be at least divided in 2 questions such as 1) how does covalent bonding work ?(especially in the context of doping) and 2) how does the depletion region form/work? Those can (and should, imo) be answered separately. They might be tagged as duplicate tho, because I think those separate questions have already been asked (at least #2 has been for sure)

Comment: Okkk I will edit this question.

Comment: Could you provide a source for where you learned 2. ? I don't think you have been taught that. Or the teacher really needs some vacations. The other points are also strangely stated, making it hard to tell whether they reflect a correct understanding (especially 3, not sure what you tried to say)

Comment: If we see a cation like cyclopropenyl cation, the way resonance occurs in this cation,I was refering to such movement of holes in the 3rd point. And I might have misunderstood 2nd point

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few assumptions/claims in your question which are a bit confusing. Some of them, I don’t really understand what you meant, and I think they might point out some underlying confusions (which is fine). For example:

> As far as I know due to polarization Al forms covalent bond

What do you mean by polarization, what do you think is polarized, and how do you think it relates to covalent bonding?.

> Is it the thermal energy gained from the surroundings which lets electrons to leave its location and move to another location(orbital) just as we see during the formation of atomic spectra

I don’t understand the parallel that you are trying to establish between the atomic spectra and this situation. I also don’t understand the link that you seem to imply between thermal energy and the “formation” of atomic spectra. You could observe atomic spectra at 0K

Apart from this, I think your main question is:

> But why would adjacent Si donate one of its electron to Al?

I think there is another misunderstanding implied in the formulation. Covalent bonds are not about donating electrons (that would be closer to ionic bonding). To keep it simple, it’s more about “sharing” them. You can check the wiki page for covalent bonding to learn more about it, it is an important distinction. Basically, two atoms forming a covalent bond will put an electron pair “in common”, so that they each have “one more valence electron”. So in your case Si, is not “losing” an electron; both Si and Al are “gaining” one.

As to the reason why Si is more than happy to share with his buddies, it is quite straight-forward to explain in simple terms. You already know about the octet rule. Well, silicon has four valence electrons. So it also wants to bond with 4 neighbours to obtain 8 electrons. Atoms are not particularly racist, so Si doesn’t care if it shares with another Si or an Al, as long as it gets its electron to satisfy its valence.

You’ll note that this answer does not address how that leads to doping and formation of free electrons or holes because your question has nothing that specifically relates to it (your doubts are "one step before" that). But you are welcome to ask questions about it later if you need.

Comment: By donating electrons I meant about the adjacent silicons of aluminium other than the bonding ones........in a nutshell the movement of holes

Comment: The link between thermal energy and atomic apectra I wanted to establish is that lets say two silicon molecules are sharing two electrons, it happens to be tht one electron gains enough energy to leave that bonding orbital and change its position to fill a hole. I was assuming that.

Comment: By polarization I meant the tendency of electron density to lean more towards cations

Comment: There are indeed some little misconceptions in there. But does my answer answer your question or is there some stuff you don't understandin it?

Comment: To be honest I am still confused. I have no issue regarding electron sharing between Al and Si but my confusion is regarding the process of hole filling? As far as I know Si's which are close to Al but are not bonded with it might have their electrons jumped from their orbital to fill the hole of Al. I am not sure if this is the correct process but if it then why would those electrons do that?

Comment: There's no filling of holes during bonding (pun not intended). In fact the whole point of doping is to introduce holes, isn't it? Would be a shame to fill them. They will only be filled if, for some reason, a free electron was to pass by and see the cosy free spot. I don't fully understand your question and what lead you to it

Comment: Will those electrons release energy while occupying those holes?

Comment: If te free electroms of silicons occupy the new holes(due to doping) how does new free electrons generate to cause holes to kove(apparently)?

Comment: Again, I must repeat. Electrons of silicone are not filling holes during bonding. There is no (or almost no) free electrons in a p doped material, unless you do something specific to it, but then it's another question.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Okay I guess I misunderstood earlier. So does thefree electrons just pass ofver those gaps/holes and make octet filled for a certain amount of time and just moves on like that? By free ekectrons I meant the negligible amount of electrons that shifted to conduction band.

Comment: I was thinking earlier that they fill the holes and lose energy and that energy is gained by another electron and goes on.